# Trigger automated Docker Hub build on another public GitHub repo change

Tags: git, github, docker, dockerhub

I've set up an automated build using Docker Hub for a public repo.

However I want to trigger the build process when another public GitHub repo received a new commit.

It is possible to use "Repository Links" but those only rebuild when another **Docker Hub** repo changed. I want to rebuild when another **GitHub** repo (not owned by me) changed.

**What can I do about this?**

[image]

Comment: fork the project and have a cron job [syncs](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) your fork to the original project then have the webhook defined on your fork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Repository Links feature is definitely only for other Docker Hub repositories, and not github repositories.

Indirectly, it's possible to accomplish this in a few different ways.

If the third party github repository is associated with another Docker Hub Automated Build, then you could set up a repository link with that. Then, when the third party repo is built, that other corresponding Docker Hub build will run, firing off your repository link.

The other way would be to set up a third party system to watch the third party github repository, and trigger some sort of update in your github repository. This, in turn, would trigger your automated build.

Yet another approach would be to have some small service that watches for changes in the third party github repository, and then assemble and call in a webhook to your automated build. The webhooks feature is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/